# How i get RadGridView column summation?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

i am using  Telerik tools in `Win forms`   i couldn't get sum of column in `rad text box` 
 know how to do in normal grid view any suggestion pleas ?

```
 int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < radGridView1.Rows.Count-1; ++i)
    {
       sum += int.Parse(radGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
    }
    radTextBox1.Text  = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't know what language is that, but you are converting an `int` into `string` and then it into `int` again. Is this correct, and if so why?

Comment: c# --- i convert grid cell value to INT

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this approach and it works fine on my end with RadGridView, as long as Column[5] has valid numeric values:

```
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < radGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; ++i)
        {
            sum += int.Parse(radGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
        this.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Also, you can consider the summary rows functionality for the purpose: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-summary-rows.html

Comment: Yes, as long ... I would rather use TryParse http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using column index, why not use column name?

From
sum += int.Parse(radGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

To
sum += int.Parse(radGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString());